# AADSTS700016 ERROR when I try to get access to my outlook calandar with python

Tags: python, azure, api, outlook, o365-flow

I'm trying to get access to my outlook calandar using the following code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from google.auth.transport.requests import Request
from O365 import Account
from O365 import Connection
from O365 import FileSystemTokenBackend

from configparser import ConfigParser
file='config.py'
config = ConfigParser()
config.read(file)


def authenticate_outlook():
   # authenticate microsoft graph api credentials

   credentials = (config['account']['outlook_client_id'], config['account']['outlook_client_id'])
   token_backend = FileSystemTokenBackend(
       token_path=config['account']['outlook_token_path'], token_filename=config['account']['outlook_token_filename']
   )
   account = Account(credentials, token_backend=token_backend)
   if not account.is_authenticated:
       # not authenticated, throw error
       account.authenticate(scopes=config['account']['outlook_scopes'])

   connection = Connection(credentials, token_backend=token_backend, scopes=config['account']['outlook_scopes'])
   connection.refresh_token()

   print("Authenticated Outlook.")
   return account
# authenticate outlook credentials
outlook_acct = authenticate_outlook()
```

And i'm using this config.py file:

```
[account]
outlook_client_id = "86ae4814-fad2-4cc0-b76e-57bd4b20476c"
outlook_client_secret = "06ecc895-b04d-4578-9c3c-b5a8ccc026ab"
outlook_scopes = ["basic", "calendar"]
outlook_token_path = "./credentials/"
outlook_token_filename = "outlook_token.txt"
previous_days = 40  # retrieve this many past days of events
future_days = 365  # retrieve this many future days of events
```

Then I get this error:
AADSTS700016: Application with identifier '"86ae4814-fad2-4cc0-b76e-57bd4b20476c"' was not found in the directory 'z7fs3'. This can happen if the application has not been installed by the administrator of the tenant or consented to by any user in the tenant. You may have sent your authentication request to the wrong tenant.

I checked that i'm using the good app ID and the secret ID, They match with my app on AZURE, I don't ound the issue yet.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The issue indicates that there is a mismatch between the tenant where your app is registered and where you have stated that your app is registered in either the application code or the portal.
You must set the tenant ID in your codE for the application. This is usually found in the web.config or app settings files.
Then, using the same tenant ID that you specified in your code, you must register the application on the portal. Make sure your application ID and client ID are the same on both sides, and that all of the values in your app settings/web.config are the same as what you have in the portal.
Also, using the ID in the Client secret section instead of the `Application (client) ID` is a common cause of this problem.

[image]